# Passing server side data from ejs to Ajax

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

I've created a table with data from the server side for an admin to approve.

[image]

I'm using - MongoDB, NodeJS and Express with an EJS view. I encountered a problem when I tried to use JQuery with Ajax requests in order to pass back the unique id and an approval status of the data when the user clicks the button under approved or disapproved.

so I keep getting all the id's of the data passed back.

here's a sample of my code

```
<!-- EJS -->
<table class="table table-hover m-0 tickets-list table-actions-bar dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="datatable">
                                                        <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>
                                                                <b>S/N</b>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th><b>Name</b></th>
                                                            <th><b>Department</b></th>
                                                            <th><b>Status</b></th>
                                                            <th><b>Review</b></th>
                                                            <th><b>Approve</b></th>
                                                            <th><b>Disapprove</b></th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </thead>

                                                        <tbody>
                                                        <% profileData.forEach(function(item, index){ %>

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><b><%= index + 1 %></b></td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <a
                                                                    <span class="ml-2"><%= item.lastname + " " + item.firstname %></span>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </td>

                                                            <td>
                                                                <a
                                                                    <span class="ml-2"><%= item.department %></span>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <% if (item.approved === 'pending'){ %>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <span class="badge badge-secondary">Pending</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <% } else if (item.approved === 'approved'){ %>
                                                             <td>
                                                                <span class="badge badge-success">Approved</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <% } else { %>
                                                             <td>
                                                                <span class="badge badge-danger">Disapproved</span>
                                                            </td> 
                                                            <% } %>

                                                            <td>
                                                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect waves-light btn-sm"><i class=" fi-clipboard"></i></button>
                                                            </td>

                                                            <td>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light btn-sm" id="btn-success"><i class=" fi-check"></i></button>
                                                            </td>

                                                            <td>
                                                                <button type="button" id="disapproved" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm"><i class=" fi-cross"></i></button>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <% }); %>

                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
```

jQuery/Ajax

```
<% profileData.forEach(function(item, index){ %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function(){               
                    $('#btn-success').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log('select_link clicked');

                        var userId = <%- JSON.stringify(item.userId) %>;
                        console.log(userId);
                        var data = {};
                        // data.Id = userId;
                        data.message = "approved";

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: JSON.stringify(data),
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            url: 'http://localhost:8080/',                      
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log('success');
                                // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                            }
                        });

                    });             
                });
            </script>

            <% }); %>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ejs. But why you wrap the script section inside `foreach` loop?

Comment: true, but that's the only way I can get my data since it is a set of data coming from the server side

Comment: You should use `input type="hidden"` to pass `item.userId` on the loop in table. and use only one script to handle click event. Also, because you have each button on each line use should capture event on class selector not the id.

Comment: As much as I understand a little of what you're saying, please I would like a demonstration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another simple way:
First add on each success button an `id="<%= item.userId %>"` and attach an onclick attribute like this.

```
<td>
    <button type="button" id="<%= item.userId %>" onclick="approve(this.id)" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light btn-sm" id="btn-success"><i class=" fi-check"></i></button>
</td>
```

Then in js you can use the function this way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function approve(id) {
       var userId = id;
       console.log(userId);
       var data = {};
       // data.Id = userId;
       data.message = "approved";

       $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: JSON.stringify(data),
              contentType: 'application/json',
              url: 'http://localhost:8080/',                      
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log('success');
                  // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
               }
         });
    }    
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll post it in answer section. On the table you shoud add an input hidden type inside each row:

```
<% profileData.forEach(function(item, index){ %>
<tr>
    <td><b>
            <%= index + 1 %></b>
        <input type="hidden" class="item_id" value="<%- JSON.stringify(item.userId) %>" /></td>
    <td>
        <a <span class="ml-2">
            <%= item.lastname + " " + item.firstname %></span>
        </a>
    </td>

    <td>
        <a <span class="ml-2">
            <%= item.department %></span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <% if (item.approved === 'pending'){ %>
    <td>
        <span class="badge badge-secondary">Pending</span>
    </td>
    <% } else if (item.approved === 'approved'){ %>
    <td>
        <span class="badge badge-success">Approved</span>
    </td>
    <% } else { %>
    <td>
        <span class="badge badge-danger">Disapproved</span>
    </td>
    <% } %>

    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary waves-effect waves-light btn-sm"><i class=" fi-clipboard"></i></button>
    </td>

    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light btn-sm"><i class=" fi-check"></i></button>
    </td>

    <td>
        <button type="button" id="disapproved" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm"><i class=" fi-cross"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<% }); %>
```

And you only need one script section like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){               
                $('.btn-success').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log('select_link clicked');

                    var userId = $(this).closest("tr").find(".item_id")
                                        .first().value;
                    console.log(userId);
                    var data = {};
                    // data.Id = userId;
                    data.message = "approved";

                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/',                      
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log('success');
                            // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        }
                    });

                });             
            });
        </script>
```

So at this point, the event will be listen on every `btn-success` button, and It's only run once

Comment: Okay. I didn't notice your ajax call. Basically you use it as wrong way. the method should be pass as `method` property in ajax object. Take a look on the jquery page. Also I updated my answer already http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/